# Is there a way to "share" a link to an entire site (like we can with questions and answers)?

Tags: support, badges, hyperlinks, sharing, share-this

Sometimes I share links on Reddit to questions and answers on Chinese.SE.  When sharing URLs via the "share" button, we get a link like `https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/42218/8099` wherein `8099` is my user ID.  Then we get [badges](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) when enough people click on the link.

However, sometimes I need to share a link to the whole site (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/k70n1y/online_community_app_or_website_for_posting_small/geou3hl)), and not a particular question nor answer.  Sure, I can copy/paste the URL `https://chinese.stackexchange.com/`, but I don't think I can add my user ID `8099` to this like with questions and answers.

**Question**: Is there a way to "share" a link to an entire site (like we can with questions and answers)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, the only three badges that are related to link sharing are [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster), and [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Badges related to sharing links]

And the description of all three of them is the following:

> Share a link to a **post** later visited by ### unique IP addresses

(emphasis mine)

If you want to have user IDs added to site links so that they count towards existing (or new) badges, you should probably post this as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).